# most pythonic may to pass a nested list into formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the best way to pass this:

```
board = [['X','o','o','o','o','X'],
['X','o','o','_','_','X'],
['X','o','o','_','_','X'],
['X','o','o','o','X','X'],
['X','o','o','o','X','X'],
['X','o','o','_','X','X'],
['_','o','o','o','X','X']]
```

into this:

```
"""
    ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
    ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║ {} ║
    ╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝

    """
```

With formatting? Note: the lists are vertical based in the board definition, so a simple for loop won't work.

Comment: You may want to redefine your example slightly with coordinate tuples so we can see where rows and columns are ending up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `board` is the board and `fmt` is that format string, unpack it with `*` after you flatten it using any method you like, such as a generator expression:

```
>>> print(fmt.format(*(item for row in board for item in row)))

    ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
    ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ X ║ X ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ o ║ _ ║ _ ║ X ║ X ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ _ ║ _ ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ X ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ X ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ _ ║ X ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ X ║ _ ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ X ║ X ║
    ╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Or `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(fmt.format(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(board)))

    ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
    ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ X ║ X ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ o ║ _ ║ _ ║ X ║ X ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ _ ║ _ ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ X ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ X ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ _ ║ X ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ X ║ _ ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ X ║ X ║
    ╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Or you can use a plain `itertools.chain` and unpack the `board` with `*` first:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(fmt.format(*itertools.chain(*board)))

    ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
    ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ X ║ X ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ o ║ _ ║ _ ║ X ║ X ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ _ ║ _ ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ o ║ X ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ o ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ X ║ X ║ X ║ o ║ o ║ _ ║ X ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ X ║ _ ║ o ║ o ║ o ║ X ║ X ║
    ╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```